# open virtual keyboard from chrome (osk.exe)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, wamp

It's one of these questions again (execute local.exe file from chrome web browser).

I know that this is not possible (at least not in an easy way)

What I want to do is to open the virtual keyboard on windows machines stored in the folder

> c:/windows/system32/osk.exe

I know that the simple

```
<a href="file:///C:/Windows/system32/osk.exe">Run virtual keyborad</a>
```

Don't work (for obvious reasons).

So how can I make it work? If its not possible to do this, how can I solve this issue? I really need to be able to open a virtual keyboard by clicking on a link on my webpage.

Any other virtual keyboards that I can make use of that the user don't have to download in order to make use of it through my web-page?

**Specs**

I will run my website in kiosk mode (in chrome) using a 27" Acer touch monitor (there will be no physical keyboard), running on a windows7 computer. I'm using Wamp as my webserver, I.E the webpage is accessed through a local network.

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: "_I know that this is not possible_" "_So how can I make it work?_" I'm a coder, not a miracle worker, Jim.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible. Live with it. You can not execute any program on the client machine. The browser is sandboxed. However you can make a javascript equivalent like [this example](http://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/)

Also, touch devices often provide a system-level virtual keyboard. For example when you click on a input box on android, the system will show a virtual keyboard. You can also check if that is the case. Even if it's not, if you are going to use a fixed number of devices on your local network and have direct control over them, it is possible to make them behave that way.

Comment: Is it possible to inject your example on any page and open a keyboard on any formfield, even if the page does not implement the code?

Answer (score 0):

Don't sweat it brother. I know how we coders always want to get our way. But sometimes, we learn to live with the fact that somethings are not "safe" and must be enforced as "NEVER DOs!".

However, you can build your own browser application (using any of the browser controls). You can then have the browser application open an osk whenever needed via a button on the browser application (not on you web application).

The JavaScript keyboard option is the most advised though.